# Why are FetchedResultsController delegate methods not being called for deleted records?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Just wondering if anyone else has found that deletes synchronised via iCloud are not triggering the `fetchedResultsController` delegate methods to be called on the device importing the transaction logs?

The transaction logs get imported because I get a `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` notification but the fetchedResultsController methods don't get called.

Inserted or updated records transaction imports results in the delegate methods being correctly called.

Calling `performFetch` correctly updates the result set but usually calling `reloadData` on `UITableView` was sufficient to get the UI updated correctly.

This also works if I call `save` on the context after merging the changes - never had to do that before.

```
[self.managedObjectContext mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];

NSError *error;
if ([self.managedObjectContext hasChanges]) {
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&error];
}
```

Any idea why only deletes are not triggering the fetchedResultsController delegate methods ?  Seems to be a new issue suddenly.  I am pretty sure I never had this issue previously - perhaps someone else could confirm this behaviour with one of the [sample apps here](http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/).

EDIT
It seems checking [moc hasChanges] sometimes return NO but calling [moc save] still causes the fetchedResultsController to then call its delegate methods.